# RestSharp synchronous request in windows phone

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-7.1, restsharp

Is there a way (any, no matter how) to simulate synchronous requests using restsharp?

I'm developing an app which has to wait for a successful login response to navigate forward, it is a pain to be passing callbacks all over my code just to check stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx).

Then with an extension method like:

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
    {
        public static Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteTask (this IRestClient restClient, RestRequest restRequest)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> ();
            restClient.ExecuteAsync (restRequest, (restResponse, asyncHandle) =>
            {
                if (restResponse.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
                    tcs.SetException (restResponse.ErrorException);
                else
                    tcs.SetResult (restResponse);
            });
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

You can make calls like:

```
var restResponse = await restClient.ExecuteTask(restRequest);
```